# Is it fine to create new builds to your production in react?

Tags: reactjs, npm-build

I am working on a react webapp which has its dev server on my local computer and I push its commits (from `git`) to my gcp instance. Each time after all the upgrades, I do a `npm build` and then put that build to my production. Just wanted to know if is it the right way? Does creating multiple builds affect anything including code or website performance? I mean creating `build bundles` everyday? Is that fine or should I follow some other approach?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Run a build optimizes performance, can save a few miliseconds of load time to the end user and it minimizes the number and size of files the user gets, but it is worthy to run a build only when your going to deploy your app to production.

In my opinion on development the build it's not that necessary so I recommend to only push the commits.
If you're interest in testing the perfomance of your app you can [read this react article](https://reactjs.org/docs/perf.html) that discusses testing performance on development builds using perf.

Best Regards.

Comment: so you're saying best practice isn't to create a new build everyday rather use dev server until you feel the upgrades from now on won't be at that frequent basis?

Comment: Yes the best pratice it's to run a build when you're ready to deploy to production.